# multiple languages translation issues with Localizable.strings file

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, localizable.strings

we use Localizable.strings to support multiple languages. But for some languages, such as Polish, the words has gender. So, the two words can't just be concatenated directly. We have many "Verb + Noun" strings. And we support many languages with different grammars. 
Do you meet such problem？

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could create formatted strings (with some `%@`)

Admitting your sentence is associated to the key `key1` and your word with gender to the key `key2`, your code would look like :

```
NSString *totalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"key1",nil),NSLocalizedString(@"key2",nil)];
```

Comment: Hi，we use %@ in Localizable.strings, in order to solve the position issue of verb and noun. such as "Add %@" = "Add %1$@". But I'm not familiar with other formats. What references should I check? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem couple projects ago (with also a Polish language). IMHO the problem is unresolvable. You basically can construct the phases like this with `` `@"{Noun} {Verb}" `` strings. But later we facing exactly the same problem that NSHipster warned about:

> DON'T. This cannot be stressed enough: don't subdivide localized strings. Context will be lost, grammatical constructions will be awkward and unidiomatic, verbs will be incorrectly conjugated, and you'll have missed the point entirely—taking great effort to make something worse than if you hadn't bothered in the first place.

You can find how to do it and why you shouldn't here: http://nshipster.com/nslocalizedstring/